# V basic Bootstrap example: JS components not working, no collapsing functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, filepath

I'm attempting a very basic Bootstrap tutorial example.  None of the collapsing functionality (ie, all Bootstrap code referenced, I believe) is working.  My file structure is correct, with index.html in the same folder as the bootstrap folders CSS, Fonts, and Javascript, where the min.xx files I am referencing are located.  But, I believe the issue lies there, with referencing filepaths.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1">
 <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5
elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the
page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/
3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/
1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <style>

 .box {
 background-color:#d3d3d3

 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

 <div class="container">

 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>

 <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>

 </div>


 </div>

 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/
jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files
as needed -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The F12 key will open the developer console on most browsers. Other than that, the example markup you've shown so far does not have anything that uses the collapse plugin.

Comment: THanks - I guess I need to read up more outside of this class.  My script is directly copied from the instructor's and it seems to work fine for him in the video without adding in reference to any other plugin.

Comment: If I zoom the browser in, the Hello World dynamically collapses perfectly, using the above code.  However, the "content" columns do not.  Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided does not seem to be using the bootstrap collapse function.

The basic collapse layout for bootstrap is as follows;

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should work immediately once on the page. Please visit the [bootstrap website here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse) and see their live examples.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly.  A shame that his approach ought to be scrapped in favor of this.  No shortcuts, I guess.

Comment: So, simply doing 

 `<div class="container">

 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>

 <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>

 </div>`

Won't give me collapsable columns a la: "Example: Stacked-to-horizontal" on [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css)?